# Передать изображение в UIImageView (Swift 3)

Tags: xcode, swift

Пытаюсь передать картинку из галереи в новый `ViewController`, но возникает ошибка

> Creating an image format with an unknown type is an error fatal error:
>   unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Код:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        if let im = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
            let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "editImage") as! EditImageViewController
            vc.imageView.image = im
            self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            print("Something went wrong")
    }
    imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

В чем ошибка?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте принимать картинку так

```
class EditImageViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    var image: UIImage!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        imageView.image = image
    }
}
```

А передавать так

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    if let im = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "editImage") as! EditImageViewController
        vc.image = im
        present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        print("Something went wrong")
    }
    imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Потому что похоже, что Вы пытаетесь вставить image в еще недоступный imageView